# How should I map a continuously random variable in O(1)?

Tags: javascript, random, dictionary, statistics, probability

Given a uniformly distributed random number in [0, 1), how can I map the result depending on what region the number is in? Here is a naive solution with a snippet from [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pryszkie/jvxMn/):

```
function mapRandomNumber(){
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    if(randomNumber < 0.2){ // 20%
        return 0;
    } else if(randomNumber < 0.3){ // 10%
        return 1;
    } else if(randomNumber < 0.5){ // 20%
        return 2;
    } else if(randomNumber < 0.65){ // 15%
        return 3;
    } else if(randomNumber < 0.9){ // 25%
        return 4;
    } else { // 10%
        return 5;
    }
}
```

But what if I have tens or hundreds of cases? That would mean tens and hundreds of if-elses, which is not elegant and difficult to modify.

One O(1) answer for simple cases (for rational probabilities), is to take the random number, discretize it, and map those outcomes. Here's an example with 3 numbers:

```
numberMap = {
    0: 0, // 1/3%
    1: 0, // 1/3%
    2: 1 // 1/3%
}

function mapRandomNumber(){
    var randomNumber = Math.random(); // [0, 1)
    randomNumber = randomNumber*3; // [0, 3)
    randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber); // 0 or 1 or 2
    // returns zero 2/3 of the time, and returns one 1/3 of the time
    return numberMap[randomNumber];
}
```

This doesn't really apply to irrational probabilities and is probably inefficient for large maps where many of the mappings should return the same result.

I would prefer a general solution for any programming language that has a constant time complexity (O(1)).

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: `parseInt()` is not for converting floating point to integer. Use `Math.floor()` here.

Comment: Instead of discretizing your spectrum and making a map, have you considered making a set of limits?

Comment: It's not a homework question. It's for a personal project and I would need to churn out lots and lots of random numbers efficiently. Yeah, I'll use Math.floor.

Comment: Squid, how do I make a set of limits programatically without conditionals? Is there a way without using conditionals?

Answer (score 0):

```
var limits = [
    0.001,
    0.01,
    0.1,
    0.3,
    0.30001,
    0, // this deletes this index from the output
    0.7,
    0.9,
    1];

function mapNumber(num) {
    for (var i=0; i<limits.length; i++) {
        if (num <= limits[i])
            // here we simply map to the index, but the values in the limits
            // array could also be used to store the mapping value.
            return i;
    }
}

console.log(mapNumber(0)); // 0
console.log(mapNumber(0.000000001)); // 0
console.log(mapNumber(0.015)); // 2
console.log(mapNumber(0.4)); // 6
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as my first solution, cleaned up a bit. The problem here is conditionals are still being used which eats up cpu. If I had, say, 10 million "limits", then in the worst case, I have to execute 10 million if-statements to see if my random number falls in the last region. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: If you know that your limit list is sorted (or if you make it sorted) then you can use various algorithms to avoid the linear behavior. [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) comes to mind. It reduces your number of tests from `n/2` to `log_2(n)` on average. Give it a try and let me know if you need help after an attempt or two.

Comment: I clarified the question to include O(1). That is what I meant when I say mapping the random variable. I am not interested in non-O(1) solutions.

Comment: If you must have constant time, using the bucket approach you suggested may very well be the only option (assuming that you can deal with the loss of continuousness). I don't recall any reasonable algorithms which would do what you want in constant time, but I'm not an algorithms expert so I may simply not know it.